# How is illusory superiority reconciled with the false-consensus effect?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, bias

On one hand, people often seem to exhibit various forms of [illusory [self-]superiority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority), perhaps the best known example of that being the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

On the other hand, the [false consensus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consensus_effect) aka [social projection](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15745863) seems to work in the opposite direction of making the subject believe he is more similar to others (by making the subject assume the others are [more] similar to him).

Is there an integrative account of these two effects? When does one dominate and when does the other?

Comment: Related: [What self-image do most people have?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16283/7001)